# Time Out in WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service within a console application. I have a server method which returns a list of companies depending on the sector passed as a parameter.

The flowing code  fails and throws a time Out exception after 5 minutes.

```
List<Company> companies = EService.GetCompanies(1755);
```

While in the app.config I have already set the time Out:

```
sendTimeout="23:20:00" receiveTimeout="23:20:00" maxReceivedMessageSize = "1000000000"                        
closeTimeout="23:20:00"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that the real problem is to know why GetCompanies takes more than 5 minutes.

Comment: The server takes a lot of times to returns a result because we have a lot of companies.

Comment: @BilelChaouadi Sounds like a poor excuse. Databases are designed for extremely fast data retrieval. For example: Azure table storage can do a search over 160M records in under 1/10th of a second. Is there an index on your sector column?

Comment: i'm using a WCF service which developed by another Developer, and the data base was designed by another company, and i can not modify neither the WCF service nor the database, the service works fine for some sectors and fails for certain sectors.

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting back? - can you write it out with full namespace. It is possible the timeout is coming from the database code within the GetCompanies method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey In your binding configuration, there are four timeout values

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="InTimeout"
         sendTimeout="00:20:00">
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The most important is the `sendTimeout`, which says how long the client will wait for a response from your WCF service. You can specify `hours:minutes:seconds` in your settings - in my sample, I set the timeout to 25 minutes.

The `openTimeout` as the name implies is the amount of time you're willing to wait when you open the connection to your WCF service. Similarly, the `closeTimeout` is the amount of time when you close the connection (dispose the client proxy) that you'll wait before an exception is thrown.

The `receiveTimeout` is a bit like a mirror for the `sendTimeout` - while the send timeout is the amount of time you'll wait for a response from the server, the `receiveTimeout` is the amount of time you'll give you client to receive and process the response from the server.

In case you're send back and forth "normal" messages, both can be pretty short - especially the `receiveTimeout`, since receiving a SOAP message, decrypting, checking and deserializing it should take almost no time. The story is different with streaming - in that case, you might need more time on the client to actually complete the "download" of the stream you get back from the server.

There's also openTimeout, receiveTimeout, and closeTimeout.

You can also refer that link [**WCF Timeout**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761079/wcf-service-timing-out)

Hope it helps you

Comment: As you can see, i set the time Out to 23 hours, and i get an exception after 5 minutes, how can you explain that ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i figure out that the problem come from the server.